# How can I select a special part of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to select something between curly brackets in JavaScript.

For example I have got this sentence as a string: `this {is} for {test}`
and I would like to get `{is}` and `{test}` from it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: basic regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```js
const str = 'this {is} for {test}';
const res = str.match(/(\{[^\}]*\})/g);

console.log(res);
```

[Regex101 explanation](https://regex101.com/r/tX2dbc/1)
[image]

Comment: thats great . thank you very much indeed :))

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions it will be:

```js
const result1 = "this {is} for {test}".match(/\{([^}]+)\}/gi);

console.log(result1); // ["{is}", "{test}"]
```